# Return the number of months between two dates as an array of strings

Tags: javascript, function, date, calendar, arr

```
//So I have and array of months
 const months = [
     'January',
     'February',
     'March',
     'April',
     'May',
     'June',
     'July',
     'August',
     'September',
     'October',
     'November',
     'December'];

// If the input is startDate: 1-1-2019 & endDate: 3-15-21
// It should return an array like so:

const monthsBetweenDates = [January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August, September, October, November,December, January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August, September, October, November, December, January, Feb, March];

// The returned/new array should have all months between the start and end date above in Order, duplicated needed in order as well.
```

Thank you so much for your help and time. Please let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: are the dates 'dates' or are they strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plain arithmetical solution

---

Considering the goal, I'd say solving the task with basic math makes more sense, than dealing with the `Date` type.

All you need is:

- [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) date strings (`m-d-yyyy`) of start and end dates into start/end months and years (`mStart`, `yStart`, `mEnd`, `yEnd`):

```
const [mStart, , yStart] = start.split('-'),
      [mEnd, , yEnd] = end.split('-')
```

- calculate total length of period (in months, including both start and end) as

```
12*(yEnd-yStart)+(mEnd-mStart)+1}
```

- return an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) of corresponding length, where each item will be taken from the source `month` array shifted one position rotationally:

```
months[(mStart-1+i)%months.length]
```

---

You may find complete demo below:

```js
const startDate = '1-1-2019',
      endDate = '3-15-2021',
     
      monthsBetweenDates = (start,end) => {
        const months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
              [mStart, , yStart] = start.split('-'),
              [mEnd, , yEnd] = end.split('-')             
        return Array.from(
          {length: 12*(yEnd-yStart)+(mEnd-mStart)+1},
          (_,i) => months[(mStart-1+i)%months.length]
        )
      }
      
console.log(monthsBetweenDates(startDate,endDate))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stringToDate(_date,_format,_delimiter)
{
            var formatLowerCase=_format.toLowerCase();
            var formatItems=formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
            var dateItems=_date.split(_delimiter);
            var monthIndex=formatItems.indexOf("mm");
            var dayIndex=formatItems.indexOf("dd");
            var yearIndex=formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
            var month=parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
            month-=1;
            var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex],month,dateItems[dayIndex]);
            return formatedDate;
}

var startDate = stringToDate('01/01/2019','mm/dd/yyyy','/')
var endDate   = stringToDate('08/15/2021','mm/dd/yyyy','/')

var startYear  = startDate.getFullYear();
var startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
var endYear    = endDate.getFullYear();
var endMonth   = endDate.getMonth();

months=['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER'];
myArray = [];

  for(let i=startYear;i<= endYear;i++){
     for(let j=0; j<12;j++){
       if (i == startYear && j >= startMonth)myArray.push(months[j]);
       if (i >  startYear && i <     endYear)myArray.push(months[j]);
       if (i == endYear   && j <=   endMonth)myArray.push(months[j]);
     }
  }
       
       console.log(myArray);
```